# Set ImageView using URL

Tags: android, imageview, base64, android-imageview, bitmapimage

I have an Image on my server. The URL for the image is something like:
http://www.mydomain.com/123456uploaded_image.jpg

I am trying to set this image to my ImageView. Here is the code that I tried:

```
    try{
            String url1 = myeventimagearray[position];
            URL ulrn = new URL(url1);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)ulrn.openConnection();
            InputStream is = (InputStream) con.getInputStream();
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            if (null != bmp)
                iveventimg.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            else
                Log.i("Image","Not set");

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When I try this, my imageview is empty, i.e., it doesn't set the image view and i get this System err in my logcat:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: libcore.net.http.FixedLengthInputStream cannot be cast to com.example.eventnotifier.Base64$InputStream

Base46.java is a file I found from the internet that Encodes and decodes to and from Base64 notation.

Any idea why I'm getting this System.error?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use URlImageViewHelper, it will take care of loading url into imageview.

[Refer this](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper)

It will take care of caching, loading in background etc. by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely getting an exception because you are trying to do network io on the main thread.  Consider using a loader or an AsyncTask to load your image.

Check your logs, I bet you are printing a stack trace in the auto generated catch block.

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
     final Bitmap b = bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(myeventimagearray[position]).getContent());
     iveventimg.post(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
         iveventimg.setImageBitmap(b);
       }
    });
  }
}).start();
```

Comment: I have edited post to give a detailed explaination about the error. Is it still cz im doing network IO on the main thread?

Comment: The exception that you are getting is for some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy answer but you should use a caching system.

See https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-BitmapCache for an excellent one!

Simply swap the ImageView for [NetworkCacheableImageView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-BitmapCache/blob/master/sample/src/uk/co/senab/bitmapcache/samples/NetworkedCacheableImageView.java) and then use `loadImage( "http://....", true );`

Answer (score 0):

Use Picasso to fetch image from url. Implement `'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'` in `build.gradle` and in java

```
Picasso.get()
  .load(url) // http://www.example.com/123456uploaded_image.jpg
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)
```